# How do I create a rank using dates in powr bi?

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I want to create a rank among the review_at dates column.
When I tried:

```
Ranking_Dates = RANKX(ALLSELECTED('Table'),[Ranking_Dates2] , MAX('Table'[reviewed_at]),DESC,Skip)
```

It returns only values of 1.

I did a datediff to see how it should look like.

```
Ranking_Dates2 = DATEDIFF(CALCULATE(MIN('DataDNA Dataset Challenge - March 2023'[reviewed_at]),ALLEXCEPT('DataDNA Dataset Challenge - March 2023', 'DataDNA Dataset Challenge - March 2023'[index])),MAX('DataDNA Dataset Challenge - March 2023'[reviewed_at]),DAY)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
Ranking_Dates = RANKX(ALLSELECTED('Table'),'Table'[reviewed_at],MAX('Table'[reviewed_at]),DESC,Skip)
```

Remember that RANKX does not break ties